# Can I create a user that only has Network permissions?

Tags: permission, user-account, settings, preferences, administrator

I would like to create an account that only has permission to modify the Network preference pane in the System Preferences (in it's entirety).

Is such a feature feasible? Comparable to Windows, where you can have an account that serves as a full blown administrator with all permissions, but have various other accounts that only have control over one aspect of operation (in this case the Network (more specifically, all settings pertaining to the Network preference pane in the System Preferences). I'm convinced there isn't any native support for this, and I feel like I'm willing to try anything at this point.